# i didn't find "import org.springframework.jbdc.core.JsbcTemplate"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

i was searching for an hour to find a solution to my problem and i i'm using maven to pom.xml to find the library of this import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate

**my pom.xml**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
 <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
 <name> Spring boots test</name>
 <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

</project>
```

*the result was :-*

```css
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.sample:test1 >--------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring boots test 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.626 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-21T08:41:16+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test1: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.sample:test1:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-jdbc:pom:3.2.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate, There are multiple things that you can do.

- Check the maven repository for the jar of `spring-boot-starter` under `org > springframework > boot`
- Sometimes the download might be interrupted or may be due to failure it would not have downloaded correctly, in that case delete the `spring-boot-starter` under `org > springframework > boot` and build again
- You can clean and verify the maven project again (I would suggest to do this from the console, to do this go to the folder where your `pom.xml` exist and execute `mvn clean verify`)

Comment: it didn't solve the problem .